the algebraic dimension of infinite dimensional Hilbert space is strictly larger than its Hilbert dimension?
For a Hilbert space, we can define two dimension, the first is forget its norm and take it as a vector space, its dimension I call it algebraic dimension. Another way is to use its maximal orthogonal set, and call its cardinality its Hilbert dimension. My question is whether they’re same. I guess algebraic ones is strictly bigger than the Hilbert one but I can’t prove it.(In infinite dimensional case) What I know is that if H is an infinite dimensional Hilbert space, than it’s algebraic dimensional is the same as the cardinality of the whole space it self.
I also find this result on wiki, but without proof. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space#Hilbert_dimension

Algebraic dimension, also called Hamel dimension.    Hilbert dimension, also called orthonormal dimension.  Perhaps try to prove: if the (infinite) orthonormal dimension is $n$, then the Hamel dimension is $\ge 2^n$.  Cantor already proved that $2^n > n$.

@Gedgar Yes, I want to prove this but I have no idea about it.

This is not true. Let $A$ be the cardinality of an orthonormal basis, $B$ the cardinality of a Hamel basis, and $H$ the cardinality of the Hilbert space. Then it is clear that $A \leq B \leq H \leq 2^{\aleph_0} \times A^{\aleph_0}$ (so long as $A$ is nonzero). If we take, for instance, $A = 2^{\aleph_0}$, we see that these inequalities collapse into equality.

Why the last inequality holds? I can only estimate that H is smaller than R^{A}=2^{A}, R is real number and N is natural number.

@wichard Every element of $H$ has a representation as $\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty x_i a_i$ for some sequence of complex numbers $x$ and sequence of basis vectors $a$. There are $|\mathbb{C}^\mathbb{N}| = 2^{\aleph_0}$ ways of choosing the $x_i$ and $A^{\aleph_0}$ ways of choosing the $a_i$. You can try for a sharper bound by enforcing that the $a_i$ be distinct and the sum converge, but this doesn’t buy you any improvement.
